# Compare two arrays show key exemple[x].text

Tags: python, list, selenium

I have the following situation

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 30]

out = [i for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(array1,array2)) if e1!=e2] or False
print(out)

## Output:  (8)
```

Works fine. But I need it for the following type of variable which I get via selenium

```
array1 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "classTeste")
array2 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "classTeste")

## this array have a object .text
## array1[0].text
## how to use the function below with this type of variable?

out = [i for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(array1,array2)) if e1!=e2] or False
#not work
out = [i for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(array1.text,array2.text)) if e1!=e2] or False
#not work
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"this array have a object .text"* No, it doesn't. Each of its elements have a `.text` attribute. So you need to compare `e1.text != e2.text`.

Comment: can you provide the samples of actual lists where in you do `array1[0].text` for all the elements?

Comment: @DeepSpace i got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @Dev its similar to first example, array1[0].text == 1

Comment: The idea is for "out" is for it to compare the items in both lists and if they are not the same, return False, right?

Comment: `out = [e1.text if e1.text==e2.text else False for (e1,e2) in zip(array1,array2)]` Maybe something like this?

Comment: stale element reference exception is because you lost the references of the elements you grabbed in `array1` or `array2` or in both. Add up the HTML of the elements, if you don't provide the required information. its only you, who will stop helping himself.